# Power switch has changed directions for power

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, walls

Hall bathroom wall Light switch has changed directions all of the sudden with no one doing anything to it to turn on the light, instead of flipping up the switch as usually now you have to flip it down to get the bathroom light to work. What is going on, is this potentially dangerous?

Comment: Is it possible you have another switch somewhere else that also controls this light -- a "3-way" switch setup? Because this is exactly how such a switch would behave if someone flipped the other switch to the opposite position from where it was. It's not too likely for a bathroom, but it's possible.

Comment: Does the switch have a labeled "ON" and "OFF" position? If so, are the words now upside down? If not, there's a 99% chance that this is part of a 3-way switch circuit and that someone's flipped the other switch (perhaps accidentally).

Comment: Semi-serious question: do you have a prankster in the house? Flipping a switch sounds like something I would have done in my misspent youth, if I’d thought of it.

Comment: There is no label of on/off on the switch and no pranksters in the house…the bathroom light switch is outside the bathroom door before entering it. Its a two switch, one switch is for the hall light and the other is for the bathroom light. The hall switch is still working as it normally does. There are also two switches in the bathroom above the sink one is for the ceiling fan and the other for a separate ceiling heater. No other switches in the hall or bathroom.

Comment: No on/off labels on the switch... yup, it's a 3-way switch. There is another switch somewhere which also controls this light.  Someone changed that one.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for most mechanical switches to turn direction is for someone to remove it and turn it around(upside down).

If no one has done this, then replaced the switch now.

Turn off the breaker first and check there is no power at the switch.

This sounds like a basic one switch, one light set up.  Is there anyway another switch also controls this light?  With a two switch, one light set up(three way switches), a seldom used second switch might have been flipped the other way.

Two switches for a bathroom is quite rare/odd, unless two doors/entrance ways into it.

Comment: It's almost certainly a 3way switch.  I've never heard of a switch "changing direction".

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson   The only way I can even think of it being possible, is if the metal connector came loose, but the handle is still catching it a bit   But that seems like one in a million chance.  Better than 50% for a plank.

Comment: Its a two switch, its very odd but its a old house. The switch is set outside the bathroom door in the hall and one switch is for the hall and the other is for the bathroom. The hall switch is still working as it normally does.

Comment: @Naynay  That sounds like a single switch/single light, two switches together but controlling different lights.  Would replace that switch now, it will probably fail completely either on all the time or off.  Are you sure no one is trying to prank you?

Comment: "There is no label of on/off on the switch and no pranksters in the house…" Obviously this is a 3way unless it's a very old switch.

Comment: Thank you. Got someone to take the duel cover plate off & there are two separate switch devises under the plate. The one for the bathroom lights was visibly broken, so replaced it. It was put right side up correctly, the one that was there prior was flipped around and put in up side down so the switch had to be flipped down to turn it on which always struck me as odd. Now the new switch is working and you flip it up to turn on lights. The lighting though has five bulbs above the mirror and the far right one powers up slower then the rest, even after a new bulb was put in. Curious issue.

Comment: @Naynay  Thank you for the update.

Comment: Well now the switch has changed again had company over and they said the switched has changed direction earlier they went to the restroom and the switch flipped up to turn it on and then later the switch changed and you have to flip it down to turn on the bathroom light. I dont know what is going on? And no one is changing like a prankster. This is a small one level 1950s build duplex. Anyone have any ideas ?